# What other ways can I reduce the memory usage in VBA? 32 bit Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I was really hoping I could figure this out but haven't had any luck. The following VBA allows users to import data from a separate file and determine unique variables to be analyzed, initiated by a single command button. The issue occurs as the final sub is called (filtering for unique variables). I have set `.ScreenUpdating = false` and set variables back to null after use. As for the sheets in the workbook, they currently do not contain data or formulas but will need to in order to analyze the data further.

Any help in identifying heavy memory usage would be appreciated.

64 bit is unfortunately not an option either

**Located in Module1:**

```
    Global PathAndFile As String
    Global FileName As String
 Sub SelectFile()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Dim fd As FileDialog
 Dim InDir As String
 Dim wb As Workbook

 InDir = CurDir()   'Save current directory

 Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

 With fd
     .InitialFileName = CurDir & "\"     'Startup folder
     .AllowMultiSelect = False
     .Filters.Clear
     .Filters.Add "All Excel Files", "*.csv" 'Display csv files only

     If .Show = False Then
         MsgBox "User canceled without selecting."
         ChDir (InDir)  'Change back to Initial directory if user cancels
         Exit Sub
     End If
     'contains the path and filename of selected file
     PathAndFile = .SelectedItems(1)
 End With

 'contains the filename (without the path)
 FileName = Right(PathAndFile, Len(PathAndFile) - _
         InStrRev(PathAndFile, "\"))

 'Clear storage sheet
 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataTransferred").Cells.Clear
 Call rData
 End Sub

Sub rData()
'Retrieve Data
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim Datawb As Workbook

'Open Selected workbook
Set Datawb = Workbooks.Open(PathAndFile)

    With Datawb
    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Copy data and paste in new this workbook
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRow, lCol)).Copy _
    Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataTransferred").Cells(1, 1)

    End With

Workbooks(FileName).Close


'Clear Memory
lRow = 0
lCol = 0
strPathAndFile = vbNullString
strFileName = vbNullString
'Sort data
Call Worksheets("DataTransferred").VariableSelect '<<<Run-Time Error 7
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Located in Sheets("DataTransffered"):**

```
Sub VariableSelect()
'Determine unique variables out of assortment
    Dim rngDest As Range

    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataTransferred").Cells = Empty Then Exit Sub

        'Determine destination for varilables
        Set rngDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis").Range("A1")
            rngDest.ClearContents
        'Select cells with in column (B) and apply filter
        Me.Range(Me.Range("B1"), Me.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=rngDest, Unique:=True


End Sub
```

Comment: You should download the trial of FastExcelV3 and see if that helps you. http://www.decisionmodels.com/fastexcel.htm

Comment: The problem could be located inside sub rData. Workbooks.Open is changing context of ThisWorkbook to newly opened workbook. You have to refer to your workbook with DataTransferred sheet by full name (Workbooks("")) or store reference to ThisWorkbook before opening new workbook.

Comment: @smartobelix I thought `ThisWorkbook` referred to the workbook in which the code was written in. I tried referencing the workbook directly but I'm still receiving an out of memory error.

Comment: @pnuts I figured this would be easier for users as not everyone in my organization is familiar with creating a PivotTable. Is there another way to automate a pivot table based on dynamic data?